# Labelling a variable according to its quantiles [Python]

Tags: python, dataframe, quantile

I would like to split a column into 4 distinct classes and label each class by 0,1,2,3 according to the 3 quantiles.

```
This is my Dataframe
     
0      36.88
1      36.88
2      36.88
3      36.88
4      49.12
       ...  
695    80.88
696    30.98
697    31.22
698    31.22
699    31.76
Name: total_charges, Length: 700, dtype: float64
```

I then split my column according to its quantiles:

```
df['total_charges'].quantile([0.25, 0.5, 0.75])

0.25    28.750
0.50    40.970
0.75    64.335
Name: total_charges, dtype: float64
```

Now I would like to have all the values

- from 0 to 0.25 = 1
- 0.25 à 50 = 2
- 0.50 à 0.75 = 3
- 0.75 à 1 = 4

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.qcut(df["total_charges"], 4, labels=[1,2,3,4])`